# Why always viewWithTag is nil in tableview rowAtindexpath?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, tags, uilabel, tableview

im trying to get the `UILabel` from tableview cell I used `viewWithTag:` but `UILabel` i created showing always `nil` in `tableview:cellFroRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel*)[tableview viewWithTag:25];
```

`myLabel` is returning `nil`

Comment: If the label is part of the cell, use the `cell` as the receiver for the method.

Comment: You are right i used cell instead of uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, if the label is part of the cell, use the `cell` as the receiver for the method.

```
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:25];
```

If you've added `myLabel` to the [`contentView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView) of the cell - which you should - use that as the receiver instead.

```
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:25];
```

Comment: Ya i used UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:25]; instead of UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel*)[tableview viewWithTag:25];